# How can I run a command in a remote xterm?

Tags: shell, pid, csh, xterm

In a cshell script, I spin-out an xterm. From the shell where the script is executed from, I wish to execute a command (eg: banner master win) in the xterm that has been spun out from the script.

Can you suggest me a way to do that?

Do you think finding for xterm's paid would help me in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `-e` argument to the xterm when you start it

From the output of `xterm --help`

```
[-e command args ...]
```

So running the following will launch an xterm to run the watch command against the date program, with a suitable title:

```
xterm -T "Date" -e watch date &
```

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! When you have a minute, please accept the answer to confirm it as working, see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in the help area for more on this